# Ninject V2 InRequestScope: firing constructor on every request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, ninject-2

I'm having a hard time with Ninject V2's InRequestScope() for managing a UnitOfWork.

```
_kernel.Bind<UnitOfWork>().To<SqlUnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
```

I expect whenever I request the UnitOfWork via the container that the same object is always returned throughout the request. However, in the debugger I have a breakpoint on the object's constructor and whenever a request is made to the container the constructor fires as though a new object is being created.

```
var uow = CreateKernel().Get<UnitOfWork>();
```

Has anyone had similar experiences as this or am I missing something critical?

Comment: Are you sure that the object isn't getting destroyed by other means?

Comment: Also, what's your `CreateKernel` method look like?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Larsenal, the issue was infact related to how I was accessing the CreateKernal method after the initial call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone else has this problem my issue was related to the global.asax file. I was manually storing the result of CreateKernal in a private variable. Changing to access the request's created kernal via the Kernal property of the base NinjectHttpApplication class sorted the issue.